# Difference between linear map, linear transformation and operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the difference between linear map, linear transformation and operator? Is linear map a definition requiring the domain and the range have same dimension and the latter two for domain and codomian with the same dimension?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I use linear map and linear transformation to mean the same thing: a map from a vector space $V_{1}$ to a vector space $V_{2}$ and that is linear. $V_{1}$ has its own dimension and $V_{2}$ also (no need for having the same dimension). A linear form on $V_{1}$ is a linear map from $V_{1}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (and $\mathbb{R}$ is of dimension $1$).

An operator is not something that is necessarily linear. It is just any map between vector spaces. If it is linear then we call it a linear operator.